# Remote Repair/Update of Google Chrome using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

I have a script I've worked on to remotely check the version of Chrome on a users computer, and if the version is below a specified version, it will RoboCopy the correct .msi and run the upgrade.

The problem I am running into is with the version check. It appears that some machines must have had a failed upgrade at some point.

For instance, on one machine:

```
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("\\$remotePC\c$\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").productversion
```

Outputs Chrome 88.0.4324.150

```
(Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remotePC -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemProperty -Path
    HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*,
    HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | Where {($_.DisplayName -Like 
    "*Chrome")}}).DisplayVersion
```

Outputs Chrome 88.0.4324.96

I have tried running a repair and install using both the 88.0.4324.96 and 88.0.4324.150 .msi's using the following script:

```
$ChromeSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remotePC 
Invoke-Command -Session $ChromeSession -ScriptBlock {
    #repair
    Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/fa ".\googlechromeenterprise64.msi" /quiet'
    #install
    #Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I ".\googlechromeenterprise64.msi" /quiet'
    }
Remove-PSSession $ChromeSession
```

Neither seems to be able to repair or upgrade Chrome. If the version matches, the Install works perfectly to upgrade. Other than manually touching each machine, is there a way to repair a Chrome install that appears to have a failed upgrade?

Items of note:

- Updates are typically handled via SCCM, but I do not have access to SCCM.
- I am running this script as a batch. This upgrade can run in the background without user engagement.
- Because this is a batch, I'm trying to avoid having to uninstall completely, though I am working on a script that could be used as a "one-off" for uninstall/install, but we will need to contact the user to verify they aren't using Chrome so we avoid any loss of work.

Comment: `-ArgumentList` expects comma separated values (*an array*). Also, use the full path to the executable.

Comment: I used relative paths for the example, but use full paths in my script. Sorry for the confusion on that. As for the argumentlist, it has worked for most updates with the exception of these. I’ll try adding as an array to see if that works.

Comment: Adding the arguments as an array did not help. The problem seems to be with the previously failed upgrade. I can’t repair .96 or .150. 

I may just need to uninstall completely, but still need to try killing GoogleUpdate.exe and/or deleting the Update directory. The system/user is offline now, but will report back once I can test.